# python mallet LDA FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\d33563_state.mallet.gz'

Tags: python, mallet

It is my first time to use mallet LDA. Basically, I downloaded the mallet-2.0.8 zip file and JDK. I installed JDK, extracted mallet-2.0.8 to a destination folder. I set the MALLET_HOME.
Here is my code

```
mallet_path='C:/Users/abc/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet'
ldamallet=gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path,corpus=corpus,num_topics=20,id2word=id2word)
```

However, it gives the error:

> FILENOTFOUNDERROR[ERROR2]

I tried

```
mallet_path='C:\\Users\\abc\\mallet-2.0.8\\bin\\mallet'
```

and

```
mallet_path=r'C:\Users\abc\mallet-2.0.8\bin\mallet'
```

I got the same error msg.

Comment: I also have encountered same error

Comment: Hopefully, someone can help us to figure out.

Comment: Can you please tell me if any solution was found? I seem to facing the same problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. The error I got was as follows:

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory c:\\users\\...\\appdata\\local\\temp \\d36348_state.mallet.gz.`

Each time I tried to run the code the prefix before the underscore would change but the error name would always end with the form "~Some Alphanumeric String~_state.mallet.gz".

I tried to understand the stack trace output in the console. The line just before this error line was as follows:

`fileobj = self.myfileobj = __builtin__.open(filename, mode or 'rb')`

I googled it and found this particular [link](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1219). It is a github link where a person raised a different error, but the ending part of his error log was the same as mine. The solution to his error was an upgrade of his `smart_open` module, which `gensim` depends on, as the upgrade had fixed the issue. So i checked my `smart_open` module version and it was `1.4.x`, last updated about a year and a half ago, so I upgraded it to the version `1.5.7` and the LdaMallet code works without a hiccup.

Please check if the problem on your end is being caused because of the same reasons.

Hope it helps!

P.S. I also updated my `gensim` module alongside the `smart_open` to version 3.4.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it was because I forgot to set the environment variable %MALLET_HOME%

```
import os
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet

os.environ['MALLET_HOME'] = 'C:/.../mallet-2.0.8/'
```

Comment: After I tried your suggestion, I got the following error:

`CalledProcessError: Command 'C:/Users/20200016/surfdrive/PhD/Overig/LDAWord2vec/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input C:\Users\20200016\AppData\Local\Temp\af1031_corpus.txt --output C:\Users\20200016\AppData\Local\Temp\af1031_corpus.mallet' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: It solves my issue like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

this is the answer

```
import os
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet

os.environ['MALLET_HOME'] = 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Research_lak\\mallet-2.0.8'
mallet_path = 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Research_lak\\mallet-2.0.8\\bin\\mallet'
ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=10, id2word=id2word)
```