# Mallet with Gensim: file-not-found

Tags: gensim, lda, mallet

I try to get LDAMallet in gensim working, but get the following error

'C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\eb09f5_state.mallet.gz' not found

The code

```
ldamallet = gensim.models.\
wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path,
                   corpus=corpus,
                   num_topics=5,
                   id2word=dictionary)
```

(the num_topics is extremely small, but the test goes over 5 sentences; this has no problem in the regular gensim LdaModel)

thanks,

Comment: Are you sure that this exact code snippet is throwing the error? `LdaMallet` creates these files upon saving the model. They are not required for running the wrapper.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you resolved this? I seem to be facing the same issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671565/python-mallet-lda-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-c-u/51158086#51158086

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. The error I got was as follows:

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory c:\\users\\...\\appdata\\local\\temp \\d36348_state.mallet.gz.`

Each time I tried to run the code the prefix before the underscore would change but the error name would always end with the form "~Some Alphanumeric String~_state.mallet.gz".

I tried to understand the stack trace output in the console. The line just before this error line was as follows:

`fileobj = self.myfileobj = __builtin__.open(filename, mode or 'rb')`

I googled it and found this particular [link](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1219). It is a github link where a person raised a different error, but the ending part of his error log was the same as mine. The solution to his error was an upgrade of his `smart_open` module, which `gensim` depends on, as the upgrade had fixed the issue. So i checked my `smart_open` module version and it was `1.4.x`, last updated about a year and a half ago, so I upgraded it to the version `1.5.7` and the LdaMallet code works without a hiccup.

Please check if the problem on your end is being caused because of the same reasons.

Hope it helps!

P.S. I also updated my `gensim` module alongside the `smart_open` to version 3.4.